# Mac Mini Invisible File Problem

Tags: macos, mac-mini, file-sharing

I've got an issue where after moving a file from the desktop a shared location (mac mini) the file doesn't appear.

After duplicating the file, both the copy and the original file appear so it's not a permissions issue. Is there anything that could be causing it to ghost like that?

Both Mac and the mac mini are Mavericks 10.9.5

Comment: What do you mean from *the desktop to the mac mini*? Where is the destination?

Comment: and how do you see (or not see) the file?

Comment: Try to copy the file while holding the *option* key.

Comment: So after moving the file I can see it on the Mac mini - we use it basically as a NAS. However on the original Mac, I can access the folder, but I can't see the file I've dragged there.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dragging the file, do you see a **small green plus sign**? If you don't see this, it means that you are going to cut and paste the file, but if you can see the green plus sign it means you are going to duplicate the file into another location. By holding the *option* key, you can force duplication, and you can see the green plus sign appears.